# Java based ETL Application

Tags: spring, jpa, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I want to build a spring framework based ETL application. I should be able to create an exact copy of any table in a database. Hence, the structure of the table is not known to me beforehand. So, creation of entities is not possible within the application.
The idea is to provide some external configuration to the application for each table. The application should then be able to create an exact copy of the table.
I cannot use Spring JPA as it requires creation of entities. Thus, planning to use Spring JDBCTemplate. Will Spring JDBCTemplate be the right framework for my application?
I am not ready to use Pentaho,rather I want to build something like it with Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spark.
Here is an example of how you can do it

```java
public class DemoApp {
  SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
                .master("local[1]")
                .appName(DemoApp.class.getName())
                .getOrCreate();
  Dataset<Row> table1 = spark.read().jdbc("jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/postgres", "demo.table", getConnectionProperties(dbProperties));

  private Properties getConnectionProperties(Properties dbProperties) {
        Properties connectionProperties = new Properties();
        connectionProperties.put("user", "postgres");
        connectionProperties.put("password", "password");
        connectionProperties.put("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver");
        connectionProperties.put("stringtype", "unspecified");

        return connectionProperties;
    }
}
```

You can read several tables and after that join them or do other things you like.

Comment: I dont want to use any external application. Want to build the entire application within Spring framework.